# Why is ID blank when using create method in spec file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following code in a micropost_spec.rb:

```
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory :user
    @attr = { :paragraphs => 4, :characters => 1000, :summary => "Recap of Event" }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    @user.microposts.create!(@attr)
  end
```

And when I run my tests, I get the following error:

```
  Failure/Error: @user.microposts.create!(@attr)
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
     Validation failed: Id can't be blank
```

Is it possible to see if the id is set inside the rails console?

Comment: You should check `@user` to make sure its valid.  Maybe the factory is returning an invalid, or unsaved @user object, which is causing create to fail when it tries to create the micropost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is probably trying to validate that `id` is present with something like `validates_presence_of :id` or `validates :id, :presence => true`. You shouldn't do that, as validations on new records are always run *before* the record is saved to the database and assigned an id.